# How do I detect the scratch org "DomainNotPropagated" error from outside the org?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, mydomain

Every so often, when you create a new scratch org and attempt certain actions:

- Log in.
- Switch to Lightning Experience.
- Deploy Lightning components via SFDX or the Metadata API.

you'll see an error related to My Domain. Upon login, it looks like this:

> An error has occurred in the following section: [Exception, DomainNotPropagated]. Salesforce.com has been notified of this error.

presented in a plain, Classic-styled page.

These errors typically go away with a wait of less than five minutes, but waiting a few minutes by default doesn't cut it in a CI environment. So here's my question:

**How do I detect this propagation issue from outside the org**, i.e., by performing some DNS query? Or, alternately, **how do I detect this propagation issue via the API, without mutating the state of the org?**

What I've tried so far is primarily inspired by [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/matt-newell/cd1e1caff90fa16158ebb006c31022e8) discussing how to solve a similar issue with Visualforce pages, but what I can't figure out is which domain, specifically, causes the issue, and whether I can actually detect it locally by running `dig` against domains like `<mydomain>.my.salesforce.com` or `<mydomain>.lightning.force.com` or `<mydomain>--<mynamespace>.lightning.force.com`. So far, I haven't been able to find a domain state that correlates with the presence of the error.

Because the issue is transitory and doesn't occur a majority of the time, it's very difficult to reproduce and get reliable data.

Comment: We see this as well, though haven't noticed it sorting itself out in as short a time as 5 minutes... our CI setup basically ends up rejecting the merge and the developer has to try again (the CI creates a scratch org for every merge targeting master).